# Getting PID of the process created by xdg-open

Tags: c, exec, fork

The situation is the following: I fork the process to open an html file with the default browser. Here is how it looks in my case:

```
if ((pid=fork())==0) {
    execlp("/usr/bin/xdg-open", "xdg-open", url, NULL);
    /*if execlp failed, exit the child*/
    exit(0);
}
```

However, I want to get hold of the PID of the process (opened browser), so that I could close it later too. But I do not seem to know how could I get it. Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You should already have the PID of the child process, the man page of fork() says:

> On success, the PID of the child process is returned in the parent,
>   and 0 is returned in the child.

So in the child process you detect the 0 and run your program, in the parent pid will be the actual PID of the child.

According to your comment what will then happen is that the xdg-open process - who's PID you now now will in turn start a browser and you have no direct access to the PID of that browser process.

At present the only thing I can think of doing is creating yet another child process that you run a command such as ps or pgrep in.  You can then parse the output of that command to find the PID of the browser that is running as a child of the xdg-open.  There is an example of reading the output of a child process [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12645236/c-read-stdout-from-multiple-exec-called-from-fork)

Comment: I don't think so. The child process will run the xdg-open. However, the browser will be opened in another process, if I understand correctly. So the PID will be different.

Comment: @elena: From `man 3 exec`: `The  exec()  family of functions replaces the current process image with a new process image.` As a replacement is performed there is no need to create a new process, so no new process-id is assigned.

Comment: Yes, I read the man page. However, if you look at my example: execlp("/usr/bin/xdg-open", "xdg-open", url, NULL), you will see that the xdg-open is the replaced process image. xdg-open, in turn, opens the browser (as the url is an html page). The browser will run in a new process. So I need the PID of this process instead.

Answer (score -1):

`fork()` returns the pid of the child process to the parent.

In the child you can acquire it's own pid with the standard `getpid()`.

```
pid_t child_pid = fork();

if (child_pid < 0) {
    perror("fork");
    // error handling
} else if (!child_pid) {
    // child goes here
    pid_t my_pid = getpid();
} else {
    // parent continues here
}
```